# python iterate over list values for key

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested-lists

What is the best way to iterate over all indexes in a list which is the value of a key in a dictionary? i.e.

`mydict = {'key1': [92,4], 'key2': [1,4,3], 'key3': [1,8,2], 'key4': [9925,2,4] }`

i want to loop through each key, exaust all values in the lists and then move to the next key. using iteritems i am not able to do this. **Is there a way to do this without nested forloops**?

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
  print '{}: {}'.format(key, value)'
```

this gives me the following output:

```
key3: [1, 8, 2]
key2: [1, 4, 3]
key1: [92, 4]
key4: [9925, 2, 4]
```

i am looking to get output like

```
key3: 1
key3: 8
key3: 2
```

etc..

Comment: Ultimately you won't be able to avoid some sort of nested loop.

I'd probably write it as a list comprehension, but it would still just be a fancy nested for loop.

Answer (score 4):

The solution using *multiplication* operator `*` to get the needed arguments number for string formatting:

```
mydict = {'key1': [92,4], 'key2': [1,4,3], 'key3': [1,8,2], 'key4': [9925,2,4] }

for k, v in mydict.items():
    print((k + ' : %s\n')*len(v) % tuple(v))
```

The output:

```
key3 : 1
key3 : 8
key3 : 2

key4 : 9925
key4 : 2
key4 : 4

key2 : 1
key2 : 4
key2 : 3

key1 : 92
key1 : 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for k,v in mydict.items():  # `items()` for python3 `iteritems()` for python2
    for i in v:
        print(k, ":", i)
```

Comment: the question that i'm wondering if there is a way to do this without a nested for loop.

Comment: Code only answers aren't as helpful as those which include explanations, so it can be applied to the general case.

Also, the OP was asking for ways *other than* nested for loops.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it without nesting for loops in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
values = ((key, value) for key in mydict.keys() for value in mydict[key])
for key, value in values:
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
```

We are iterating over both mydict.keys and mydict[key] producing key value pairs. The resulting generator values yields (key3,1) then (key3,8), etc.

Comment: Probably the best option, however, this does boil down to nested for loops `((key, value)` for `key in mydict.keys()` for `value in mydict[key])`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that, as a generator, you can only do this once. If you need the `values` for reuse, you should use a list comprehension